# Ping on workstation shows a client’s domain? DNS issue?

Tags: windows-7, dns, windows-networking

I have been having issues resolving my local lan based IIS servers and SQL server instances via DNS. The issues are only present on one workstation, all others are normal.

I ran a ping on the workstation for one of the servers:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping dom-apps

Pinging dom-apps.ha.maskthis.com [205.122.122.122] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

That `ha.maskthis.com` is the munged name of a client’s Windows 2012 Active Directory LAN.  I do connect to it via vpn but not now and not for a while. dom-apps is a server on my LAN - it is not connected to the client network. The workstation is a Windows 7 Pro machine, rebooted recently more than once. I have run these commands and they didn’t change anything re this issue:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat -R 
arp -d *
```

Why would a client’s network context appear in this workstations’ ping results?

Comment: Check your network adapter settings, under Advanced, on the DNS tab, are any of the settings related to appending domain suffixes or connection specific dns settings set? also have you checked the hosts file? in the System control panel, does the full name of the system in the ha.maskthis.com domain? what you are describing is perfectly normal DNS search behavior if any one of these settings is misapplied, except that it did resolve an IP for the name, which does imply the host file.

Comment: Do you mean network adapter, tcp/ip, advanced? Oh look at that...it does show ha.maskthis.com! How on the earth did that setting get there? I've never touched this on any machine in my life and no one else uses this machine.

Comment: some enterprise DHCP servers can push search domains down, though I would have expected it to config the VPN virtual adapter, rather than the physical one. or is this a SSL or other high-level 
"VPN" which uses the physical nic? other than that, no idea. if you clear it out, does the problem go away?

Comment: The gear on the my client's side and my side is soho level - basic sonicwall router vs asus router; both running windows 2012 std. Something made the modification but I can't imagine what.

Comment: Do I change that setting to "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes"? I can't just remove the existing setting. Something else has to be set in this dialog.

Comment: select the top radio button ("Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes") and clear out the box that says "DNS suffix for this connection", or replace it with your LANs DNS suffix. Also check the system control panel, for the DNS name settings, as the radio button setting will use it for short-name resolution.

Comment: What section of cp system has dns settings? I don't find that. In the domain setting area I see the correct setting. I did find that ping issue is solved - no odd domain prefix and it will return ping based on server name. But sans reboot, or something else, the browser/iis and sql server network instances still don't resolve quite right. Can't reboot yet - long backup running.

Comment: I have rebooted now and most issues are solved. There is still an oddity with sql server's network server connection dialog but I think that must be some other topic. THANK YOU FRANK! And, still not sure what control panel dns setting you were referring to in your last post. Would like to confirm that.

Comment: the easiest way to get to the control panel System applet is by hitting the `Win` + `Pause/Break keys`., or in explorer, right clicking on Computer -> Properties. the Full name property is under the heading "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings". Click Change Settings -> Change -> More , to access the system primary dns suffix for the box.